# HighStock scrollbar customization

Tags: highcharts

Is there any way to completely hide scrollbar's buttons which contain arrow?
In addition to this, is there any way I can set the position of scrollbar such as setting y value so that the scrollbar hovers on the chart?

Setting its color to transparent doesn't help.

```
scrollbar: {
    buttonBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
    buttonBorderWidth: 0,
    buttonArrowColor: 'transparent',
    buttonBorderRadius: 0
}
```

EDIT:
Even if I hide the elements, I cannot use the space left as the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate SVG elements.

```
chart: {
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    var chart = this;

                    chart.scroller.scrollbarButtons[0].hide();
                    chart.scroller.scrollbarButtons[1].hide();
                }
            }
        },
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/fexw25Lz/

Comment: You code hides the element, but it still takes the area with width of 30px. Thus, it has the same effect as making the color transparent. Is there any way to make the element width 0px so that I can use the whole width just for scrollbar?

Comment: At this moment is not availave, but you can post your suggestion in our uservoice here: http://highcharts.uservoice.com